# If the world was perfect, how would we know how to decipher imperfections?

Tags: diseases, natural-disasters

I've always wondered that if everything was always "good", how would we know that there was something "less good" to distinguish the "good" from the "less good"? Can a world like this exist,  or would it only exist momentarily, before being destroyed by disease (for the symptoms would be indecipherable from normal human behavior) or everyone was eaten by monsters (because the humans wouldn't know that monsters where bad)?

Comment: If the world was perfect there would not be any diseases.

Comment: While that __is__ true, the diseases thing was just for an example. Other things with malicious intent could be sprung upon the world.

Comment: They could but I don't think things happening with malicious intent would be compatible with a perfect world.

Comment: For this question, you really need to define 'perfect', 'good', 'less good', and 'imperfect'. These words mean different things to different people (as the answers demonstrate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Stories would offer some understanding.

Just as we can write stories of places of perfect good, people who lived in a utopia would have stories of bad times. Many would be based off known dangers, like animals who went insane, or children who were rebellious. Even in a perfect world there would be minor dangers for people to handle, so people would understand the basics of that- sometimes a cow might run into a wall, and go insane, and need to be put down. Sometimes a person would scratch themselves, and the older ones might get sick and die.

They would as such have a basic understanding of suffering, and a vague understanding of how to handle crisis. If they met rabid animals (monsters) you get the stronger people to pelt them with rocks till they die. If someone is sick, give them extra food and love and care so that they can recover, or bring their children and grand children to them to say goodbye.

### They would have many bad ideas.

Having almost no experience with evil makes it hard to handle it. Most people would find it emotionally hard to kill monsters. They wouldn't know how to make makeshift weapons to kill them. They wouldn't know well that diseases can spread from person to person in a contagious manner.

This means a bunch of them would probably die.

### Whether they live depends on flexible and creative leadership.

Even if they don't understand evil, most societies understand obedience. A strong leader with the mental flexibility to handle danger could unite their people to handle lesser dangers and force them to fight back. A weak one could lead them to devastation. There's almost always early warnings of a crisis. How well the leadership responds to those warnings will tell how well they survive.

Comment: Thanks! that was really helpful.

Comment: Glad to have helped with your stories.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly it was Augustine of Hippo to introduce the concept that there is a grade in qualities.

To make a laymen example, let's take the NBA. It's recognized as the top basketball championship, and whoever plays there is an excellent player. However even there one can clearly see a difference between an MJ and the guy sitting on the bench the whole season.

It's a matter of logic then, after noticing the existence of different grades of goodness, extending those grades further, coming to a practical definition of "good" and "bad".

However being aware that "bad" exists doesn't mean being ready to contrast it, because it depends on how that "bad" comes into existence. To stay in the NBA example, there can be a "bad" in 3 point scoring, in passing, in defending, in free throws and so on. Each of them requires a different countermeasure, and preparing for all the theoretical possibilities is not effective.

Comment: Wouldn't all NBA players be MJs in a perfect world?